# Intersection() and Except() is too slow with large collections of custom objects

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, linq, collections

I am importing data from another database.

My process is importing data from a remote DB into a `List<DataModel>` named `remoteData` and also importing data from the local DB into a `List<DataModel>` named `localData`.

I am then using LINQ to create a list of records that are different so that I can update the local DB to match the data pulled from remote DB. Like this:

```
var outdatedData = this.localData.Intersect(this.remoteData, new OutdatedDataComparer()).ToList();
```

I am then using LINQ to create a list of records that no longer exist in `remoteData`, but do exist in `localData`, so that I delete them from local database.

Like this:

```
var oldData = this.localData.Except(this.remoteData, new MatchingDataComparer()).ToList();
```

I am then using LINQ to do the opposite of the above to add the new data to the local database.

Like this:

```
var newData = this.remoteData.Except(this.localData, new MatchingDataComparer()).ToList();
```

Each collection imports about 70k records, and each of the 3 LINQ operation take between 5 - 10 minutes to complete. **How can I make this faster?**

Here is the object the collections are using:

```
internal class DataModel
{
        public string Key1{ get; set; }
        public string Key2{ get; set; }

        public string Value1{ get; set; }
        public string Value2{ get; set; }
        public byte? Value3{ get; set; }
}
```

The comparer used to check for outdated records:

```
class OutdatedDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataModel>
{
    public bool Equals(DataModel x, DataModel y)
    {
        var e =
            string.Equals(x.Key1, y.Key1) &&
            string.Equals(x.Key2, y.Key2) && (
                !string.Equals(x.Value1, y.Value1) ||
                !string.Equals(x.Value2, y.Value2) ||
                x.Value3 != y.Value3
                );
        return e;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataModel obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The comparer used to find old and new records:

```
internal class MatchingDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataModel>
{
    public bool Equals(DataModel x, DataModel y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x.Key1, y.Key1) && string.Equals(x.Key2, y.Key2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataModel obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should *really* implement the hash code.

Comment: Hash codes are used to locate objects in hash tables, which is probably what `Except` and `Intersect` use internally to find matching objects. By returning a constant value, all objects will have the same location, and the search for matches degrades to a linear search among all candidates. You need to implement `GetHashCode` properly based on the properties used for equality.

Comment: Correct. I added a hash code and the operation takes a split second! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By having a constant hash code you have ruined the performance. Here is the internal code Intersect uses (gotten via a decompiler)

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (first == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    }
    if (second == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    }
    return Enumerable.IntersectIterator<TSource>(first, second, comparer);
}

private static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource current in second)
    {
        set.Add(current);
    }
    foreach (TSource current2 in first)
    {
        if (set.Remove(current2))
        {
            yield return current2;
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

See that it is using a `Set` internally, if you implemented the hashcode would greatly improve it's performance.

`MatchingDataCompaer` is the easier of the two so I will do that one for you.

```
internal class MatchingDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataModel>
{
    public MatchingDataComparer()
    {
        comparer = StringComparer.Ordnal; //Use whatever comparer you want.
    }

    private readonly StringComparer comparer;

    public bool Equals(DataModel x, DataModel y)
    {
        return comparer.Equals(x.Key1, y.Key1) && comparer.Equals(x.Key2, y.Key2);
    }

    //Based off of the advice from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode
    public int GetHashCode(DataModel obj)
    {    
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + comparer.GetHashCode(obj.Key1);
            hash = hash * 23 + comparer.GetHashCode(obj.Key2);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

You could potentially use the hashcode function from `MatchingDataComparer` in `OutdatedDataComparer`, it may not be the "optimial" hash code<sup>1</sup>, but it would would be a "legal"<sup>2</sup> one, and would be a lot faster than a hard coded 0.

---

<sup>1. Or it may be, I am not sure how I would include that 3rd `&&` condition

2. If `a.Equals(b) == true` then `a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()`.

   If `a.Equals(b) == false` then `a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode() || a.GetHashCode() != b.GetHashCode()`</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation Scott! I implemented the hash code and the operation is fast now.